# Registering SevenZipLib

Tags: c#, 7zip

I have "legacy" software in C# which uses SevenZipLib.

I have downloaded SevenZipLib, but I dont know how to declare:

```
using SevenZipLib;
```

[image]
I have tried adding the reference without any result.

Comment: When happens when you add the dll as reference? Does it fails?

Comment: Have you added a reference to the assembly (dll) of SevenZipLib?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you add a reference to the dll in your project/solution. Right click on your project and click Add Reference. Browse to the directory that you extracted SevenZipLib and click on the dll to add the reference.

Also, if you are able, you might look into installing the [SevenZipSharp](http://www.nuget.org/packages/SevenZipSharp/) Nuget Package as an alternative. Installing the Nuget Package will automatically download any required dependencies and add them to your project/solution. Please note that if you go with SevenZipSharp, you will have to rewrite the 7-zip part of your application to use SevenZipSharp instead of SevenZipLib.

Answer (score 0):

The file 7z64.dll which you are trying to add is a native DLL, not a .NET Assembly and not a COM component. You cannot add this dll as a reference.

Add a reference to a managed DLL or use P/Invoke to load and call 7z64.dll